Import module error for a Python function in AWS Lambda
Snippet from code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import traceback
from jwt import JWT
from botocore.vendored import requests
import time


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    app_id = $$$

    payload = {
        # Issued at time
        ‘iat’: int(time.time()),
        # JWT expiration time (10 minutes maximum)
        ‘exp’: int(time.time()) + 600,
        # GitHub App’s identifier
        ‘iss’: app_id
    }

    # Create JWT
    jwt_instance = JWT()
    encoded_jwt = jwt_instance.encode(payload, signing_key, alg=‘RS256’)

I am getting the following error in my python function for AWS Lambda. It is working locally.
Error:
errorMessage”: “Unable to import module ‘uploader’: No module named ‘jwt’“
I have tried adding lambda layer for JWT, Pyjwt. But no luck.
I am using this path in my lambda layer: python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/(jwt packages).
I have tried changing my lambda layer for Jwt package with Jwt, Pyjwt but it didn’t help

Using zip from python directory and using linux specific libraries resolved the issue

If the issue is solved, you can self-answer your question. This is encouraged on SO. You will be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours.
